# C# Application to read USB at Backend and Only my application read the usb and no other

Tags: c#, winforms, usb, barcode

I want to create an application in C# to read two usb barcode scanner. Since the barcode scanner are as HID Keyboard device, my application read the barcode scanner, but if another application is in focus it also receive the input data. Can we write a program to read input and only our application will read and no other.

Comment: Is the other application opening the USB device or is it one of those devices that just pastes data into the active window?  If it's the later, there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to global hook the keyboard, then suppress desired keys from your application.

There is a great article with complete explanation about Keyboard Global hook, you can find it here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

As bar-code readers only send specific key events, you can simply add them to your hook list and set `e.Handled=true` to suppress the key event for other applications (assuming you will use the code from the article).